# InstCountPass not working on new LLVM Pass Manager

Tags: clang, llvm, clang++, llvm-ir

I am trying to run the llvm InstCount pass in the new pass manager on a random generated c code.

1. I generated a .bc file from the c file , using command :

```
/usr/bin/clang -I/home/intern24001/csmith/install_csmith/include -c -emit-llvm randomcode-1.c -o rand.bc
```

After this I ran

```
./bin/opt rand.bc -S -stats -passes="instcount"  -o /dev/null
```

This gave me a blank Statistic report, I have built llvm with -DLLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=ON

```
===-------------------------------------------------------------------------===
                          ... Statistics Collected ...
===-------------------------------------------------------------------------===

407 bitcode-reader - Number of Metadata records loaded
  7 bitcode-reader - Number of MDStrings loaded
```

I have clang-19 in LLVM build